# How much SSDs to use on computer for DaVinci Resolve Studio?

Tags: davinci-resolve, performance, ssd

I want to build a computer for DaVinci Resolve Studio. I want to choose how much SSD to use in it.

I thought of two variants. In both variants I will not store archive files on computer on which I will work in DaVinci Resolve Studio. Only current project work files will be on computer on which I will work in DaVinci Resolve Studio. Archive files I will store in NAS or another computer with RAID.

---

Variant 1. On computer for DaVinci Resolve Studio one SSD: M.2, PCI-E x4, NVMe.

Two logical disks on it: disk C, disk D.

Disk C: Windows 10 Home 64-bit, applications including DaVinci Resolve Studio.

Disk D: current project work files.

---

Variant 2. On computer for DaVinci Resolve Studio two SSDs. Each SSD: M.2, PCI-E x4, NVMe.

First SSD. Disk C on it. On disk C: Windows 10 Home 64-bit, applications including DaVinci Resolve Studio.

Second SDD. Disk D on it. On disk D: current project work files.

---

What is better for DaVinci Resolve Studio's performance, stability, data safety?

Comment: "What is better for DaVinci Resolve Studio's performance, stability, data safety?"  You can optimize for both without sacrificing either.  For safety, you want an external RAID5 or RAID6, and an offsite backup.  For speed, you don't care about safety, because the only stuff you should use the speedy disk for is cache.  Where you choose to invest your dollars depends on what you do most frequently, too.  If you're a colorist, you get more use out of the render cache than an editor, who needs seamless, native decoding as much as possible, and fast proxy generation whenever its not.

Comment: @JasonConrad Thank you, Jason. "the only stuff you should use the speedy disk for is cache". Cache of DaVinci Resolve Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Variant 2 is gonna use 2 SSD Simultaneously, Which means IF one SSD can read Data upto 500MB/s then Both of them is gonna use Double that!

Feels Awesome, right?

But, That is not the fact.... Disk C is Only Gonna Send Huge Amount of Data to RAM when A Software Located inside Disk C is Starting.... When Finished loading It's Gonna be Back to It's idle mode....

[image: Disk C: is Local DIsk]

> That 1-3MB/s Doesn't Really Matter at all to The scale of 500MB/s.
> So You can go with 1 Big SSD rather than 2 SSDs.
> I would Suggest Doing that, You can Save Some bucks!

*Also in my case, I was Downloading a File in Disk C. That's Why it Jumped to **14MBp/s*** But Usually, Even when Resolve will be Running Speed will be Jumping around 1.8MB/s

I was Worried about Performance Just Like you, Months Ago... I changed my build, Switched to AMD R9 then... My Solution was... Giving the SSD it's Very Own Disk rather than Storing C:Local Drive On it! i Store Local drive in HDD, all The Small and Not-So-Performance-Needed Software in there... The Softwares on which I needed Performance (eg: Blender, Cinema 4D, Fusion) I Installed them inside a Folder In Disk X (Disk X is on SSD)